# Xamarin Forms - API Post Call not calling

Tags: c#, api, post, mobile, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin Form app, from the Master Page menu, in the Portable project, I call Content page InfoScreen into the Detail. InfoScreen code looks something like this:

```
        public InfoScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListAccounts();
    }

    public void ListAccounts()
    {
        SearchAccounts SA = new SearchAccounts();

        SearchAccountRequest searchAccountRequest = new SearchAccountRequest("000123456789", "","","","");
        var searchAccountResult = SA.SearchAccountAsync(searchAccountRequest);
    }
```

Notice that on load it calls ListAccounts, located in a class in the Portable project, which looks as follows:

```
        public async Task<SearchAccountResult> SearchAccountAsync(SearchAccountRequest searchAccountRequest)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:00/api/");
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchAccountRequest);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("SearchForAccount", content);
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (result != "")
        {
            var sessionResponseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchAccountResult>(result);
        }
```

However, when var response = await client.PostAsync("SearchForAccount", content); gets hit, it just goes back to InfoScreen and continues to load. The API is never hit, which I'm running locally on debug mode. I tested with Postman and it's working correctly.

I also tried:

```
            var client = new HttpClient();
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchAccountRequest);
        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:00/api/SearchForAccount", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchAccountResult>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
```

Same results. What am I missing?

Thanks

===============

Tried calling the DEV server, utilizing IP, works fine from Postman. Only thing I'm getting in the app is

```
Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = {null}
```

Comment: use IP or FQDN, not localhost

Comment: Thanks Jason. I can get my local IPV4 with ipconfig, but not sure how to tanslate that into a URL for my localhost:00/API...

Comment: just replace the domain name with the IP.  I've never seen :00 used as a port number like that, that may also be an issue

Comment: Sorry, the 00 its just a place holder. I did tried changing localhost for IP, didn't work, even in Postman.